How to Maintain Fixed Axis Scale in a 3D Plot (Scatter3d) Using Plotly js?
I’m working with a 3D Point Cloud grid (Scatter3d) in Plotly.js, and I want to ensure that the tick values on the x and y axes remain fixed even when I rotate or zoom in/out. How can I achieve this?
I tried using tickmode: array, tickvals: [], ticks: outside, fixed range: true
expecting the axis to remain fixed. However, when I zoomed in and out & while rotating, the axis changed and became floating. How can I keep the tick values fixed for both the x and y axes?
